# AS3 Array of objects - not so simple finding/sorting

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

Imagine an simple AS3 Array of objects like this:

```
var arr:Array = new Array ();
arr.push ({xx:"50", yy:"200"});
arr.push ({xx:"75", yy:"50"});
arr.push ({xx:"25", yy:"100"});
arr.push ({xx:"75", yy:"75"});
```

I need to do the 'math' on array in a such a way that I get this as result:

(logic should be first smallest yy and then smallest xx)

```
1. xx:"75", yy:"50"
2. xx:"75", yy:"75"
3. xx:"25", yy:"100"
4. xx:"50", yy:"200"
```

Any hint, example... opinion, please help :)

Answer (score 4):

You can have a secondary sort by using an array to contain your sort fields. Also, I am assuming that you want to do a numeric sort :

```
var array:Array = new Array;

array.push({xx:75, yy:75});
array.push({xx:75, yy:50});
array.push({xx:100, yy:25});
array.push({xx:200, yy:35});
array.push({xx:75, yy:550});

array.sortOn(["yy","xx"], Array.NUMERIC);
```

If you don't use NUMERIC with those strings you have, it's going to sort them as if they are strings. For example :

```
1
10
100
2
20
3
300
```

as opposed to

```
1
2
3
10
20
100
300
```

Comment: I just can't believe it that I omitted the second sort :)
Thank you prototypical that is what I was looking for.

Comment: Don't you just love it when you take the time to answer someone's question, and they take the time to thank you for the solutions via a comment -- but they forget to ACCEPT the answer! haha :)